# AngularJS - is it dependency injection or multiple inheritance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, dependency-injection

Most of the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) I have read regarding [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) talks about dependency injection.

When defining a controller, you can *inject* other classes into it, making their operations/properties accessible from the calling class.

So where, I have say, a `contentTypeFactory` defined, and I *inject* it into a `contentTypeController`, I thereby get all the benefits of the factory and can call properties and methods within it.

ie: `app.controller('contentTypeController', ['$scope', '$log', 'contentTypeFactory', ...`

From an OO perspective, this looks a lot like multiple inheritance, rather than dependency injection.

Can someone please clarify this?

Comment: Multiple inheritance to me means inheriting the interface and behavior of parent classes.  I'd consider angular pretty clear dependency injection, and the objects are composed of services, etc.

Comment: From a OO perspective this is composition not inheritance.

Comment: I don't think it's inheritance, because if some other code elsewhere called `contentTypeController.myMethod()`, it wouldn't look for `myMethod()` in `contentTypeFactory`.  It would only look in `contentTypeController`.  You could create a wrapper method inside `contentTypeController` that called `contentTypeFactory.myMethod()`, but as michael said, that would be composition, not inheritance.

Answer (score 6):

I think the simple answer is that what you describe is not multiple inheritance.

JavaScript supports prototypal inheritance which is not multiple inheritance.

When you use dependency injection, you are favoring composition over inheritance. The dependency is a "HAS A" relationship. It is not an "IS A" relationship.

In your particular scenario, your controller "HAS A" contentTypeFactory. It is not a contentTypeFactory. Your controller delegates work to it.

I hope this answers your questions.